# Can't fix the code of the jQuery section below

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Twitter feed</title>
    <style>
    body { width: 600px; margin: auto; }
    ul { list-style: none; }
    li { padding-bottom: 1em; }
    img { float: left; padding-right: 1em; }
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #333; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="biebster-tweets">
    <script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
        <li>
            <img src="{{thumb}}" alt="{{author}}">
            <p><a href="{{url}}">{{tweet}}</a></p>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>       
</ul>


<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>

<script>

(function() {

    var Twitter = {
        init: function( config ) {
            this.url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + config.query + '&callback=?';
            this.template = config.template;
            this.container = config.container;

            this.fetch();
        },

        attachTemplate: function() {
            var template = Handlebars.compile( this.template );

            this.container.append( template( this.tweets ) );

        },

        fetch: function() {
            var self = this;

            $.getJSON( this.url, function( data ) {
                self.tweets = $.map( data.results, function( tweet ) {
                    return {
                        author: tweet.from_user,
                        tweet: tweet.text,
                        thumb: tweet.profile_image_url,
                        url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str
                    };
                });

                // For future lessons, research $.deferred, viewers. :)
                self.attachTemplate(); 
            });
        }
    };

    Twitter.init({
        template: $('#tweets-template').html(),
        container: $('#biebster-tweets'),
        query: 'tutspluspremium'
    });

})();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

This code is taken from a video tutorial of jquery. When the author was working with this code, it was running successfully. but when i'm trying to use this code there is showing an error here -->

```
 this.url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + config.query + '&callback=?';
```

basically, error is in the url link. How can i fix it?? Anyone help me please..

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use version 1 of the Twitter API which is no longer active. You'll need to update the code to use v1.1.

API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Comment: i can't fix it. help me to fix it please... @mikehomme